# How to force htaccess to index.php if no file or parameters specified

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want that if the user enters only site url without specifying any file or any parameters like site.com or site.com/ , then they should be redirected to site.com/index.php but if they enter any file like site.com/somefile.php or give any parameters like site.com/?param=val , then htaccess should not do anything with it and let it run.

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess, just add this line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This way apache will look for an `index.php` all requests to yoursite.com & yoursite.com/.
There is no need to add any Rewrite condition rule! Plus, certain servers don't allow rewrite conditions.

In wamp, Rewrite is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your **very first rule** in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\s
RewriteRule ^$ /index\.php [R=302,L]
```